# My laptop keeps losing sound

Tags: windows-8, audio

I have read about similar problems online. As suggested, I unchecked the box in the sound control panel to give it exclusivity, and I also had to disable and re-enable my sound to get it to work. The trouble is, although this works, I lose my sound the next time I turn on the computer. It comes back each time I have disabled and re-enabled it, but I get the message "this device is being used by another application". I must be stopping the application being used by disabling the sound. How do I stop the application from taking control of my sound and how do I find what the application is? I worry about malware! I have a Packard Bell EasyNote TE.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to your playback devices and open your speakers that keeps going out, then you can go to advanced and un-check "allow programs to take control of this unit" if it's a malware then try chancing the name of this unit.

Just keep in mind when you change the name of the unit and you are using programs like Skype you will need to go to your Skype settings and put on the newly named speakers :D